# Getting multiple errors while trying generate grpc files using protoc-gen-entgrpc

Tags: go, grpc, protoc, grpc-go, ent

- Even after installing **protoc-gen-entgrpc** with this command

> go install entgo.io/contrib/entproto/cmd/protoc-gen-entgrpc@latest

still getting multiple errors with protoc-gen-entgrpc

This are the errors I got,

```
Could not make proto path relative: entpb/entpb.proto: No such file or directory ent/generate.go:4: running "protoc": exit status 1
protoc-gen-entgrpc: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable --entgrpc_out: protoc-gen-entgrpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
ent/proto/entpb/generate.go:2: running "protoc": exit status 1
```

Configurations:

-> Go Version - 1.19

-> Protoc-gen-go - v1.27.1

-> libprotoc 3.19.3

-> MacOS

**Note: protoc-gen-go is working properly tried generating normal grpc code with manually written .proto file.**

Thank you in advance :)